# CPP extension and multiline literals in Haskell

Tags: haskell, preprocessor, conditional-compilation, ghc

Is it possible to use CPP extension on Haskell code which contains multiline string literals? Are there other conditional compilation techniques for Haskell?

For example, let's take this code:

```
-- If the next line is uncommented, the program does not compile.
-- {-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

msg = "Hello\
  \ Wor\
  \ld!"

main = putStrLn msg
```

If I uncomment `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}`, then GHC refutes this code with a lexical error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( cpp-multiline.hs, cpp-multiline.o )

cpp-multiline.hs:4:17:
    lexical error in string/character literal at character 'o'
```

Using GHC 6.12.1, cpphs is available.

I confirm that using [cpphs.compat](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2005-March/008173.html) wrapper and `-pgmP cpphs.compat` option helps, but I'd like to have a solution which does not depend on custom shell scripts. `-pgmP cpphs` does not work.

P.S. I need to use different code for GHC < 6.12 and GHC >= 6.12, is it possible without preprocessor?

**UPD**. In addition to the accepted answer of Ganesh, I also found that another workaround is to put all conditional declarations in a separate module with `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` and thus avoid CPP in the modules with multiline strings.

Comment: Why not use `"Hello" ++ " Wor" ++ "ld!"`?

Comment: Because `"Hello\ whitespace+ \ World!"` is Haskell 98. Because there is some code around which uses it. Because `" ++ "` takes more space (and I dislike code beyond 80 columns). And finally, I'd like to write a patch without re-wrapping and re-formatting every multiline string in the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cpphs now has a --cpp option itself, which I think makes the compat script unnecessary: see the cpphs 1.3 entry at http://haskell.org/cpphs/

I think you'd need to pass `-optP --cpp` to GHC (as well as `-pgmP cpphs`) to enable this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the GHC user manual addresses this: [Section 4.10.3.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#cpp-string-gaps) reads

> A small word of warning: -cpp is not friendly to “string gaps”.. In other words, strings such as the following:

```
strmod = "\
\ p \
\ "
```

> don't work with -cpp; /usr/bin/cpp elides the backslash-newline pairs.
>
> However, it appears that if you add a space at the end of the line, then cpp (at least GNU cpp and possibly other cpps) leaves the backslash-space pairs alone and the string gap works as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to add trailing spaces after \, but cpp just reports a warning `backslash and newline separated by space`, and the code still does not compile. Using GNU cpp 4.4.3.